# Android MultipartEntityBuilder upload text field utf8

Tags: android, facebook, multipartentity

I'm using `MultipartEntityBuilder` to upload an image to Facebook.
when ever i put the `"message"` field with value in Hebrew i see `"????"` in the photo inside Facebook.

I guess it has to do something with the encoding.

When i tried to use the `builder.setCharset(Charset.forName("utf8"));` and i get an error that i don't have a "source" field (this is the image data). the charset probebly unable Facebook to find my source.

how can i set the charest to this line:

```
   builder.addTextBody("message", message);
```

in the deprecated StringBody class i was able to set it, but now i don't understand how.